# Clicking on React Link to refresh data

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I am just a beginner in React JS. Currently writing sample based on the article from [Routing React Apps](https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-react-apps-the-complete-guide). There is a navigation menu with items Home, Cars, and About. When the Cars  is clicked first time, it gets the data and renders them. The data is hard coded in the example app. However I am connecting to a web service and would like the data to be fetched whenever the Link 'Cars' is clicked. Is there a way to define event for the navigation Link? There were suggestions to use Transitionto and TransitionFrom. However they are not the right options. I have explored the lifecycle methods, but none of them get re-executed when clicking on a Link.

Comment: maybe sharing your code would help!

Answer (score 0):

Like most of the component of react/html, `Link` have the `Props` `onClick` which you can give a function where you could fetch what you want

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alexandre for input. I missed to run the lifecycle methods. Finally during debugging found that when a Link is clicked, it calls the componentWillMount method. I moved the logic of fetching data into the componentWillMount method and it works now.